# Фильтрация Spring

Tags: java, spring

когда создаем запись с одинаковым названием и описанием, потом ищем по названию.
В выборке запись задваивается, можете помочь исправить фильтрацию
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Часть контроллера

```
 @PostMapping("filter")
    public String filter(@RequestParam String filter, Model model)
    {
            List<Post> result1 = postRepository.findByTitleContaining(filter);
            List<Post> result2 = postRepository.findByMtextContaining(filter);
            List<Post> orResult = new ArrayList<>();
            orResult.addAll(result1);
            orResult.addAll(result2);
            model.addAttribute("posts", orResult);
            return "notes";
    }
```

Класс интерфейса

```
package com.IK.notes.Repo;

import com.IK.notes.Models.Post;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.List;


public interface PostRepository extends CrudRepository <Post, Long>
{
    List<Post> findByTitleContaining(String title);
    List<Post> findByMtextContaining(String mtext);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `List<Post> findByTitleContainingAndMtextContaining(String title, String mtext);` если хотите применить выборку сразу по двум полям

Comment: @azlov, привет можно поподробнее

Comment: @azlov, не работает, ошибка тут `(List<Post> result = postRepository.findByTitleContainingAndMtextContaining(!!!!title, mtext!!!!!); model.addAttribute("posts", result);`

Comment: текст необходимо передавать в кавычках `""`, а не просто `!!!!title`. Попробуйте так `("!!!!title", "mtext!!!!!")`

Comment: @azlov, подсвечивает красным, сейчас добавлю скрины к посту

Comment: правильно подчеркивает. Где вы определили `title` и `mtext`? Как вариант передавать в `@RequestParam String title` и `@RequestParam String mtext`

Comment: @azlov, я пробовал так сделать, ошибка

Comment: у вас ведь в ошибке написано всё.  Вы не передаете параметры в строке запроса, что-то вроде `.../filter?title=abc&mtext=qwe`

Comment: @azlov, Спасибо что объясняете, можете подсказать как сейчас это исправить

Comment: в строке запроса не просто `localhost:8082/filter`, а `localhost:8082/filter?title=abc&mtext=qwe`. Вот эта часть `?title=abc&mtext=qwe` и есть ваше `(@RequestParam String title, @RequestParam String mtext)` в `title` пойдет значение `abc`, а в `mtext` - `qwe`

Comment: значения abc и qwe выбрал рандомно

Comment: @azlov, а через поисковую строку на странице нельзя реализовать?

Comment: что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Ошибка происходит, потому что в контроллере вы используете переменные, которых у вас нет. У вас есть переменная filter, но нет переменных title и mText. Либо используйте переменную filter, либо добавьте в параметры метода title и mText как параметры запросов

Comment: @azlov, есть форма с фильтром(добавил скрин(ключевое слово) нужно туда вписать либо заголовок(title), либо mtext.

Comment: Либо в репозитории сделайте метод который ищет по заголовку ИЛИ по тексту

Comment: @Михаил Ребров, привет можно поподробнее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил

```java
@PostMapping("filter")
    public String filter(@RequestParam String filter, Model model)
    {
        List<Post> result = postRepository.findByTitleContainingOrMtextContaining(filter, filter);
        model.addAttribute("posts", result);
            return "notes";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В интерфейсе объявляете метод, чтобы осуществить выборку по полям `title` и `mtext`:

`List<Post> findByTitleContainingAndMtextContaining(String title, String mtext);`

И в своем контроллере вызываете:

`List<Post> result = postRepository.findByTitleContainingAndMtextContaining(title, mtext); model.addAttribute("posts", result);`

Правда учтите, что `Containing` работает как оператор `LIKE` в запросе. Если нужно полное соответствие, то `Containing` опускаем:

`List<Post> findByTitleAndMtext(String title, String mtext);`

Comment: а какая ошибка? и что такое `!!!!title` и `mtext!!!!!`?